# MVC, Data in controller from model in model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress-mvc

i have some problems with my input data in asp.net mvc on controller site. My model include another model which is binded on some textboxs.

My main model Order include a model Customer (with a string property of first name).

Example main page (i use dev express controls), i give the model to the group:

```
@model Models.Order
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Main"))
{
    <div>
        @Html.DevExpress().NavBar(settings =>
            {
                settings.Name = "nbWebshopSteps";
                settings.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
                settings.Width = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage);
                settings.Groups.Add(group =>
                    {
                        group.Text = "Bestellung bestätigen";
                        group.Expanded = false;
                        group.ShowExpandButton = DefaultBoolean.False;
                        group.ContentStyle.Border.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(247, 242, 212);
                        group.SetHeaderTemplateCollapsedContent(c => Html.RenderPartial("../Main/NavBarHeaderCollapsed", c.Group));
                        group.SetHeaderTemplateContent(c => Html.RenderPartial("NavBarHeader", c.Group));
                        group.SetContentTemplateContent(c => Html.RenderPartial("PersonalData", Model));
                    });
        }).GetHtml()
}
```

My personal data pagem, which is rendered into the group (it comes from a dll):

```
    @model Objects.Customer <div>   
    @Html.DevExpress().TextBox(settings =>
            {           
settings.Name = "txtFirstName";             
settings.Properties.Caption = "Vorname";            
settings.EncodeHtml = false;            
settings.Properties.CaptionStyle.Font.Size = 14;            
settings.Width = 385;}).Bind(Model.Firstname).GetHtml()</div>
```

After the postback my customer model is empty (first name).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Order order)
{
}
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Your text box needs to be named the same as the model property - assuming you are using the default model binder - try `settings.Name = "FirstName"` or `settings.Name = "Customer.FirstName"` if firstname is part of your sub-model Customer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q356791) article.
DevExpress support recommend to use code like this:

```
@Html.DevExpress().TextBox(settings => {
    //settings.Name = "Street";
    settings.Name = ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("Street");
}).Bind(Model.Street).GetHtml()
```